# toUpperCase error using formsy-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble using the formsy-react module with a normal react application. I keep running into a type.toUpperCase() exception within the autoGenerateWrapperClass of react.

I've copied the examples from the GitHub page verbatim. My form class is;

```
 var React = require('react');
 var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
 var Formsy = require('formsy-react');
 var Form = Formsy.Form;
 var MyOwnInput = require('./MyOwnInput.jsx');

  var MyAppForm = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function () {
          return {
              canSubmit: false
          }
      },
      enableButton: function () {
          this.setState({
              canSubmit: true
          });
      },
      disableButton: function () {
          this.setState({
              canSubmit: false
          });
      },
      submit: function (model) {
          someDep.saveEmail(model.email);
      },
      render: function () {
          return (
            <Form onValidSubmit={this.submit} onValid={this.enableButton} onInvalid={this.disableButton}>
              <MyOwnInput name="email" validations="isEmail" validationError="This is not a valid email" required/>
              <button type="submit" disabled={!this.state.canSubmit}>Submit</button>
            </Form>
      );
  }
  });
```

and my custom input class;

```
var React = require('react');
var Formsy = require('formsy-react');
var Mixins = Formsy.Mixin;

var MyInput = React.createClass({

  // Add the Formsy Mixin
    mixins: [Mixins],

  // setValue() will set the value of the component, which in
  // turn will validate it and the rest of the form
  changeValue: function(event) {
    this.setValue(event.currentTarget[this.props.type === 'checkbox' ? 'checked' : 'value']);
  },
  render: function() {

    // Set a specific className based on the validation
    // state of this component. showRequired() is true
    // when the value is empty and the required prop is
    // passed to the input. showError() is true when the
    // value typed is invalid
    var className = this.props.className + ' ' + (this.showRequired() ? 'required' : this.showError() ? 'error' : null);

    // An error message is returned ONLY if the component is invalid
    // or the server has returned an error message
    var errorMessage = this.getErrorMessage();

    return (
      <div className='form-group'>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.title}</label>
        <input type={this.props.type || 'text' }
               name={this.props.name}
               onChange={this.changeValue}
               value={this.getValue()}
               checked={this.props.type ==='checkbox' && this.getValue() ? 'checked' : null} />
        <span className='validation-error'>{errorMessage}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = MyInput;
```

I am using Browserify for compliation of JSX, if that makes a difference.

Does anyone have any idea where this is coming from?

Comment: What version of `react` and `formsy-react` are you using? This error usually happens when you are creating an element from an invalid component class, for instance doing `<MyComponent />` when `MyComponent` is undefined.

Comment: 0.17.0 of formsy-react, and 0.14.0 of React. I;ve managed to move the exception on to 'React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number', which seems to be related to the formsy class.